# Paypal IPN verified but not updating database

Tags: php, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I'm using paypal IPN Sandbox to update the tables in my database when payment received. Based in my ipn log its shows OK and Verified. Here is my ipn. Also I cant receive email from my IPN.

```
include ('conn.php');
// CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
// Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
// Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
define("DEBUG", 1);

// Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);


define("LOG_FILE", "./ipn.log");


// Read POST data
// reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
// issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
$raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
$raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
$myPost = array();
foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
    $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
    if (count($keyval) == 2)
        $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
}
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
    $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
}
foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
    if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
        $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
    } else {
        $value = urlencode($value);
    }
    $req .= "&$key=$value";
}

// Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
// Without this step anyone can fake IPN data

if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
} else {
    $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
}

$ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
if ($ch == FALSE) {
    return FALSE;
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);

if(DEBUG == true) {
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
}

// CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);

// Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));

// CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
// of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
// This is mandatory for some environments.

//$cert = __DIR__ . "./cacert.pem";
//curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO, $cert);

$res = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
    {
    if(DEBUG == true) { 
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can't connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
    curl_close($ch);
    exit;

} else {
        // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
        if(DEBUG == true) {
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
}

// Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly

// Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
$tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
$res = trim(end($tokens));

if (strcmp(trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0)  {





$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
    $item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
    $payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
    $payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
    $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
    $txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
    $receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
    $payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];
    $fee = $_POST['mc_fee'];
    $citems = $_POST['num_cart_items'];
    $orderID = $_POST['custom'];
    $status = "Complete";
    $orderstatus = "Processing";


        if($payment_status == "Completed"){




         $getinfo_sql = " SELECT * FROM orders a, users b
    where
    a.userID = b.userID
    a.orderID = '$orderID'";



$getinfo = mysqli_query ($conn, $getinfo_sql);


while ($getinfo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($getinfo)) 

    {
        $custemail = $getinfo['email']; 
        $paymode = $getinfo['paymentmode']; 

    }






    if($paymode == "Full Payment")
    {


//          date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Manila');  
//
//$currentdate = date("y-m-d");
//$currentTime = date("g:i:s a");



//$audit = "INSERT INTO tbl_audittrail(   username ,  action, `date`, `time` ) VALUES(  '$sname' ,  '$action', '$currentdate',  '$currentTime') "; 
//mysql_query($audit) or die(mysql_error());        
//
            $checkn = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM notifications where orderID ='$orderID'");
while($notifs=  mysql_fetch_assoc($checkn))
    { 

            $notifIDs = $notifs["notificationID"];



    }



$seen = 0;
$stat= "Processing: Full Payment";


$updatenotif = mysqli_query($conn,"Update notifications set seen=0, details = '$stat' where notificationID ='$notifIDs'");







$message = " We have received the payment for your order OrderID: $orderID \n \n ";
                $message .= "You can download the receipt at your Order History";
                $message .= "For more info about your Order Call us at  611-1111 / 622-2222 / 633-3333";
                $message .="\n \n Thanks,  \n MVRAM ";


                mail($custemail, 'Payment Received', $message, 'From:noreply@dbtk.megabuslines.biz');





                mysql_query($conn,"UPDATE orders SET `paymentstatus` = '".$status."', `orderstatus` = '".$status."' WHERE `orderID` = '".$orderID."'") or die(mysql_error());
    }





        }else{





        }   















    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
} else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
    // log for manual investigation
    // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
    if(DEBUG == true) {
        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
    }
}
```

Comment: *I got deadline for project in 2 hours*? Really...

Comment: yes sir for school project

Comment: consider revising question so desired output is clear to readers, it is unclear what you are asking

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you break the code into parts that can be debugged and fixed more easily.

Since you're working with PayPal IPN, you should first test that the IPN response is correctly recieved and verified.

If your logger works, then first debug that part using the log file.

If you find troubles fix the part of getting IPN data and verifying.

Once you're sure that the first part of IPN works you continue debugging the rest of the code faster by using this technique:

1) Test the IPN again and write the contents of $_POST into your log file using the returns of `var_export($_POST, true)`
2) Open your log file and check that you'll have there the full array of $_POST that IPN sent you
3) Copy that array and fake your original $_POST data into your script: $_POST = array(..fields from the log..);
4) Now comment out all the first part of the script that does the IPN verification, and only leave there the faked $_POST
5) Now you can manually access your script as if you were the PayPal's IPN robot by opening example.com/paypal_ipn_script.php

Now you can continue debugging the rest of your script's sql queries and see which is failing, by hitting F5 and using print_r(), var_dump(), die(), etc. All this without having to make a new paypal payment for every test and so speed up the debugging process :)

Comment: Thank you sir you save my life. Last 2 mins lol thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm using paypal IPN Sandbox to update the tables in my database when payment received.Try this code full start to end .

```
    $data = $_POST;
    $url = 'https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr';
    $data['cmd'] = '_notify-validate';

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array(
        $curl, 
        array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
            CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => 1,
            CURLOPT_POST           => 1,
            CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
            CURLOPT_URL            => $url,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS     => $data
        )
    );
    if(!($result = curl_exec($curl))){
        die('Error: "' . curl_error($curl) . '" - Code: ' . curl_errno($curl));
    }
    curl_close($curl);
    if ($result != 'VERIFIED') {

        die('Fraud IPN on Varification.');
    }
        $item_name        = $_POST['item_name'];
          $item_number      = $_POST['item_number'];
          $payment_status   = $_POST['payment_status'];
          $payment_amount   = $_POST['mc_gross'];
          $payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
          $txn_id           = $_POST['txn_id'];
          $receiver_email   = $_POST['receiver_email'];
          $payer_email      = $_POST['payer_email'];
          $ctIdcustom       = $_POST['custom'];

          //your action here
```